# How to remove ticks and labels of dropped off factors in a box plot

Tags: r

I am plotting a box plot of price across levels of cut in diamonds dataset. Since I am not interested in last two factor levels, I included only the first three.

```
boxplot(price~cut, data=diamonds,  
     subset=(cut%in% c("Fair","Good","Very Good")))
```

However, this still leaves the ticks for the dropped off levels(premium and ideal). I found how to remove all the axes labels. But I am interested only to remove the ticks and labels for the dropped levels. Also is there a way to order the selected levels according to their mean value? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset the data.frame to not include those levels. Don't forget to drop levels.

```
myx <- droplevels(diamonds[diamonds$cut %in% c("Fair","Good","Very Good"), ])
boxplot(price~cut, data=myx)
```

Comment: Thanks Roman. Have any idea how to arrange the boxplots according to their averages?

Comment: @Vasile Order factor levels according to their respective means. You will find answers on how to do that here on the site. Try the search function.

Comment: Ok will do it. Thanks